# JSF: Insert String Date Of Month-Day-Year Into Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-date-functions

I have Date in my java blue print that is format as month-day-year. 
This is the code for it

```
public String getFormattedDate() {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(dueDate);
}
```

I want to convert or insert this date into mysql prepared statement using the same format at month-day-year. But some how I can't get it to work.
I have something like this

```
ps.setString(5, out.getFormattedDate());
```

and when I run my code I get this error message

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date
>   value: '04-01-2017' for column 'DueDate' at row 1

This is my the insert statement I am using, I case if it help

```
String query = "INSERT INTO Checkout (FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, BookTitle, DueDate) "
            + "VALUE (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

I was hoping that some could help me.

Comment: Please explain more that _"not working"_ . What do you get in DB ?

Comment: I am getting nothing in the database because it's giving me MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: error.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL works with DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.
[MYSQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html)

Maybe you can use STR_TO_DATE():

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a String value into a Date value.
Your DueDate column is a date value, so you have to change it to varchar or when you execute a select you have to use the DATE_FORMAT function.
So you have two options:

*Use the DATE_FORMAT function:

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DueDate,'%m/%d/%Y') AS 'FormatDate' FROM Checkout`

(this select returns a String value)

*Change DueDate to varchar in MySQL.

Hope i solved your/someone else problem. (A little late).